# Nginx configuration for wordpress that runs as subdir djanggo

Tags: nginx, wordpress, django

I have a wordpress and django app with nginx configuration like i describe below:

```
# django
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
# wordpress
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.domain.com;

    root /path/to/wordpress;
    index index.html index.php;

    location /{
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

url at this moment

- domain.com        --> Django
- blog.domain.com   --> Wordpress

this configuration worked properly but i want to configure nginx in order the wordpress can run as subdir **domain.com/blog/** from djanggo with only one port configuration

url which i expected

- domain.com        --> Django
- domain.com/blog/   --> Wordpress

Comment: Your `proxy_pass` directive is invalid. I guess you meant `unix://path/to/gunicorn.sock`?

Answer (score 0):

You need two `location {}` blocks inside one `server {}` block, one pointing to django with `proxy_pass` and another pointing to wordpress. You can still leave the second `server {}` block serving the `blog.domain.com` site.